# GAN Model Summary Pytorch using TensorBoard?

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

Is there a way can I visualize the complete training loop for the GAN architecture in TensorBoard using Pytorch? I think it's possible using TF, but I am having a hard time to figure out one using Pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TensorboardX](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX) for this.

You can make use of **SummaryWriter** from **TensorboardX** to  create an event file in a given directory and add summaries and events to it.

The code below is an example that you can use but you have to add in the loss values, the ground truth images and the generated images yourself. I commented where they would have to go.

```
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter

import torchvision.utils as vutils
import numpy as np

REPORT_EVERY_ITER = 100
SAVE_IMAGE_EVERY_ITER = 1000

if __name__ == "__main__":

    writer = SummaryWriter()

    gen_losses = []
    dis_losses = []
    iter_no = 0

    // looping over the batches in the environment 
    for batch_v in iterate_batches(envs):

        // getting the outputs 
        // getting the generators loss 
        // getting the discriminators loss

        iter_no += 1

        // save the loss values for both generators and the discriminator every 100 steps 

        if iter_no % REPORT_EVERY_ITER == 0:
            log.info(
                "Iter %d: gen_loss=%.3e, dis_loss=%.3e",
                iter_no,
                np.mean(gen_losses),
                np.mean(dis_losses),
            )
            writer.add_scalar("gen_loss", np.mean(gen_losses), iter_no)
            writer.add_scalar("dis_loss", np.mean(dis_losses), iter_no)
            gen_losses = []
            dis_losses = []

        // save the images being produced from both the ground truth and the generator
        // it is saved every 1000 iterations
        if iter_no % SAVE_IMAGE_EVERY_ITER == 0:
            // save the generated images from the generator 
            writer.add_image(
                "fake",
                vutils.make_grid(gen_output_v.data[:64], normalize=True),
                iter_no
            )
            // add the ground truth images here
            // these will be the same throughout the cycle 
            writer.add_image(
                "real", 
                vutils.make_grid(batch_v.data[:64], normalize=True), 
                iter_no
            )
```

To view the results just run the command: `tensorboard --logdir runs` in the same directory where you ran the model training(`runs` contains the results from the training). A link will be shown which you can go to view the plots such as the one below. If you want to run Tensorboard on a remote server then you would have to add in the command `--bind_all` in the command line to access it from the outside.

### Viewing the generated images

[image]

### Viewing the loss values

[image]